# GOCD stage is green even if tests fails

Tags: maven, jbehave, serenity-bdd, go-cd

I'm trying to run some tests in GOCD and to get instant feedback from one stage by making itself in red when the tests are failing.
I mention that I'm using Serenity with JBehave, and I run the tests with mvn.

```
mvn clean verify -U
```

Answer (score 0):

If use an `<exec ...>` task to run your tests, GoCD uses the exit code to determine success/failure.

Please run the same command on the command line, and use `echo $?` (on Linux at least) to find its exit code.